# What is the right way to fetch data from network with n:m relation and store both as a model class and reference on each side in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I spent days to think&googled about how to achieve this, but still can't get any idea how it actually works...
I would appreciate if someone could give me some advise or point me to the right direction.

So in my case, I will fetch a json list from an APIs, and I just wanna store the `Shop` class into a list which will build in a `listView`.

Here's my code sample.

```
Widget buildShopList() {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: shopList.length,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 110),
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      final int count = shopList.length > 10 ? 10 : shopList.length;
      return ShopListView(
        callback: () {},
        shop: shopList[index],
      );
    },
  );
}

class ShopListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShopListView({Key key, this.shop}: super(key: key);

  final Shop shop;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(shop.type.name),
        Text(shop.name),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Shop model class

```
class Shop {
  String name;
  String website;
  String email;
  ShopType type;

  Shop({this.name, this.website, this.email, this.type});

  factory Shop.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Shop(
    name: json["name"],
    type: json["shop_types"],
    // can't figure out how to pass the shop type model class into here
    website: json["website"],
    email: json["email"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "name": name,
    "shop_types": type,
    "website": website,
    "email": email
  };
}
```

ShopType model class

```
class ShopType {
  int id;
  String name;
  String description;

  ShopType({this.id, this.name, this.description});

  factory ShopType.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ShopType(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    description: json["description"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "description": description,
  };
}
```

Here's the json will response from APIs

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "shops": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "shop name a",
                "website": "http://www.test.com/",
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "description": "this is a dummy data",
                "shop_types": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                                "name": "Type A",
                                "description": "Type A",
                        "pivot": {
                            "shop_id": 1,
                            "shop_type_id": 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "shop name b",
                "website": "http://www.test.com/",
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "description": "this is a dummy data",
                "shop_types": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Store",
                        "description": "Store",
                        "pivot": {
                            "shop_id": 2,
                            "shop_type_id": 2
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "shop name c",
                "website": "http://www.test.com/",
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "description": "this is a dummy data",
                "shop_types": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                                "name": "Type A",
                                "description": "Type A",
                        "pivot": {
                            "shop_id": 3,
                            "shop_type_id": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                                "name": "Type B",
                                "description": "Type B",
                        "pivot": {
                            "shop_id": 3,
                            "shop_type_id": 2
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "shopTypes": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Type A",
                "description": "Type A",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Type B",
                "description": "Type B",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using `built_value` & `built_collection` libraries for working with JSON data as it helps to create immutable and serializable objects easily.

Comment: @pso Thanks for the advise, just have a quick look, it seems useful tho, will have a look later on!

Comment: Do you want to save json Data in Session?

Comment: @DeepakKanyan Actually I do, cuz the shop and shop type won't change too often, so I guess I should store the data so it won't have to fetch every time I build the page.

Comment: I think you should use Sqflite https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch data From network with [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio)

```
fetchShopsAndSaveLocal() async{
    var dio = Dio();
    dio.options.connectTimeout = 4500 * 10; //45s
    dio.options.receiveTimeout = 4500 * 10;

    try {
      var param = {
        "useremail": "dpk.7@gmail.com"
        , "password": "123456"};
      var response = await dio.post(
          "https://api.test/getstores", data: FormData.fromMap(param));
      var json = jsonDecode(response.data);
      ModelStore store = ModelStore.fromJson(json);
      List<Shops> shops = store.shops;


      for (var shop in shops) {
        saveEverySingleShopInDatabase(shop);
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }
```

After that use [SQFlite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

To Save shops data in Database, after saving data in the local database, fetch data to listview every time from the database.

Comment: Thanks, it seems useful, I will have a try later tonight and accept the answer if that solve my case. Btw, if I already have my own class for network fetch by using `http` package, I could avoid to use `Dio` by just use the `SQFlite` to do what you said right?

Comment: Yes, you can use your own HTTP in place of Dio.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, it does help to solve some of my case.